# What kind of data does a SQL table need in order to build a map report in SSRS?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, spatial

Please pardon my ignorance, I'm new to spatial data. I've been tasked with creating a map report in SSRS. When finished, the report will show locations of stores participating in the same promotion.

Currently, my database doesn't contain this information, so I have to create a table first. Luckily, I have a spreadsheet that *does* contain this information, so I can just import it. However, I'm not convinced that my spreadsheet has all the information I need. It shows basic information such as store name and address, but no geographical information (which I'm assuming I need).

So my question: What kind of data does a SQL table need in order to build a map report in SSRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom table with the specific information that you want, but there are an inportant information that you mustn't forget, for example:

**From the spatial data source:**

SpatialData - A field that has spatial data that specifies the latitude and longitude of the city.

Name - A field that has the name of the city.

Area - A field that has the name of the region.

**From the analytical data source:**

Population - A field that has the city population.

City - A field that has the name of the city.

Area - A field that has the name of the territory, state, or region.

Comment: Judging by your explanation, it appears the only essential information I'm missing is long/lat. Thanks for the input!